# getDifference(ArrayList<String> one, ArrayList<String> two) Method

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to use make a Method that takes in two string array lists and outputs a list of values that are in any in one of the lists but not both, duplicates are not allowed.

this is what i have so far but i am failing 3 junit tests

```
public static ArrayList<String> getDifference(ArrayList<String> one, ArrayList<String>     two)
{
Set<String> oneSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(one);
ArrayList<String> finalone = new ArrayList<>(oneSet);
Set<String> twoSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(two);
ArrayList<String> finaltwo = new ArrayList<>(twoSet);
Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(finaltwo);
result.removeAll(finalone);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(result);
return list;
}
```

the tests i am failing are below any help as to what i can do to fix this would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
    @Test
public void testGetDifferenceWithEmptyListSecond() {
    String[]          un   = { "luke", "leah", "han" };
    String[]          duex = { };
    ArrayList<String> one  = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( un ));
    ArrayList<String> two  = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( duex ));

    ArrayList<String> actual = Lab03Two.getDifference( one, two );

    assertEquals( "The number of elements is incorrect", 3, actual.size() );
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"luke\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "luke" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"leah\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "leah" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"han\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "han" ));
}
    @Test
public void testGetDifferenceWithOverlapAndDuplicates() {
    String[]          un   = { "palpatine", "dooku", "vader", "sidius" };
    String[]          duex = { "padme", "vader", "sidius", "ackbar", "padme" };
    ArrayList<String> one  = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( un ));
    ArrayList<String> two  = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( duex ));

    ArrayList<String> actual = Lab03Two.getDifference( one, two );

    assertEquals( "The number of elements is incorrect", 4, actual.size() );
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"ackbar\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "ackbar" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"dooku\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "dooku" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"padme\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "padme" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"palpatine\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "palpatine" ));
}
}

    @Test
public void testGetDifferenceWithNoOverlap() {
    String[]          un   = { "obi-wan", "jar-jar", "anakin" };
    String[]          duex = { "r2-d2", "c-3po" };
    ArrayList<String> one  = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( un ));
    ArrayList<String> two  = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( duex ));

    ArrayList<String> actual = Lab03Two.getDifference( one, two );

    assertEquals( "The number of elements is incorrect", 5, actual.size() );
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"obi-wan\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "obi-wan" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"jar-jar\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "jar-jar" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"anakin\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "anakin" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"r2-d2\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "r2-d2" ));
    assertTrue  ( "The value \"c-3po\" was not found in the result", actual.contains( "c-3po" ));
}
```

Comment: i'm not that good at french, but isn't it `deux`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off.

Set Union:        { A, B } ∪ { B, C } = { A, B, C }   [ all elements with out duplication ]
Set Intersection: { A, B } ∩ { B, C } = { B }         [ common elements ]
Set Difference:   { A, B } / { B, C } = { A }         [ notice, no C element ]

You want set **union** - set **intersection** : (Symmetric difference) credit here goes to Phil

1. { "palpatine", "dooku", "vader", "sidius" }
2. { "padme", "vader", "sidius", "ackbar", "padme" }

( 1 ∪ 2 / 1 ∩ 2 )

{ palpatine dooku vader sidius padme ackbar } - { padme vader } = { palpatine dooku sidius ackbar }

[image: image example]

replaceAll applies set **difference**: ( oneSet difference twoSet )

The trip up comes from the **removeAll** method. It removes from **two** all the elements found in **one** but does not add all the elements that were **not** found from **one** to **two**.

The following code fixes your tests by performing **2 set differences and 1 union** to achieve a symmetric difference / exclusive or.

Exclusive or (xor), Symmetric difference

```
public static List<String> getXOR(List<String> oneArray, List<String> twoArray) {

Set<String> oneSet = new HashSet<>(oneArray);
Set<String> twoSet = new HashSet<>(twoArray);

oneSet.removeAll(twoArray);// 1. oneSet / twoArray    ,  oneSet !AND twoArray
twoSet.removeAll(oneArray);// 2. twoSet / oneArray    ,  twoSet !AND oneArray
oneSet.addAll(twoSet);     // 3. oneSet U twoSet      ,  oneSet OR   twoSet

return new ArrayList<String>(oneSet);
}
```

Comment: So you want union - itnersection sorry.. an intersection would contain sidius and vader.

Comment: the above fixes the issue and thank for the clear explanation of the solution

Comment: OP wants the symmetric difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: ps cleaned it up ;) now its "easier"

Comment: okay it was my fault i read it wrong! in fact we are both right! i didnt read "-" as minus, but as as a word concatination. nice describtion. i appologize!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<String> getDifference(ArrayList<String> one, ArrayList<String> two)
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //iterate over all elements of one
    //if two does not contain it, it's a difference -> add it
    for (String i : one) {
        if (!two.contains(i)) {
            set.add(i);
        }
    }

    //same with two
    for (String i : two) {
        if (!one.contains(i)) {
            set.add(i);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest solution here would be to traverse both lists, check if the word exists in another and if does not, add it to the Set.

```
Set<String> solution = new LinkedHashSet<>();
int n1 = one.size();
int n2 = two.size();
int i=0;
int j=0;
while (i<n1) {
    while (j<n2) {
       if (!one.get(i).equals(two.get(j))) 
            solution.add(one.get(i));
       j++;
    }

    if (i>=n2) {
      solution.add(one.get(i));
    }
    i++;
}

while (j<n2) {
  solution.add(two.get(j));
  j++;
}
```